# Using classes to get and set data buffers with arduino in C

Tags: c, debugging, arduino, buffer, lcd

I am having a problem storing data it seems in some buffers that I have made. Here is how the code looks:

Here are the definitions for each function:

WriteKeyBrdNum:

```
char Write_Keyboard::WriteKeybrdNum(TSPoint pos, Data_Buffers dB, int     selection, int count)
{
    char data;
    switch (selection)
    {
    case EXERCISE:
    {
    if (pos.y > GRABCHARSIZE * 9) //0   
    {
        //dspWord[count] = '0';
        dB.SetDataBufferChar('0', selection, count);
        data = dB.GetDataBufferChar(selection, count);

    }
    else if (pos.y > GRABCHARSIZE * 8) //1
    {       
        //dspWord[count] = '1';
        dB.SetDataBufferChar('1', selection, count);
        data = dB.GetDataBufferChar(selection, count);
        //data = '1';
        }
    else if (pos.y > GRABCHARSIZE * 7) //2   
    {
        //dspWord[count] = '2';
        dB.SetDataBufferChar('2', selection, count);
        data = dB.GetDataBufferChar(selection, count);
        //data = '2';
        }
    else if (pos.y > GRABCHARSIZE * 6) //3    
    {
        //dspWord[count] = '3';
        dB.SetDataBufferChar('3', selection, count);
        data = dB.GetDataBufferChar(selection, count);
        //data = '3';
        }
    else if (pos.y > GRABCHARSIZE * 5) //4
    {
        //dspWord[count] = '4';
        dB.SetDataBufferChar('4', selection, count);
        data = dB.GetDataBufferChar(selection, count);
        //data = '4';
        }
    else if (pos.y > GRABCHARSIZE * 4) //5
    {
        //dspWord[count] = '5';
        dB.SetDataBufferChar('5', selection, count);
        data = dB.GetDataBufferChar(selection, count);
        //data = '5';
        }
    else if (pos.y > GRABCHARSIZE * 3) //6 
    {       
        //dspWord[count] = '6';
        dB.SetDataBufferChar('6', selection, count);
        data = dB.GetDataBufferChar(selection, count);
        //data = '6';
        }
    else if (pos.y > GRABCHARSIZE * 2) //7  
    {       
        //dspWord[count] = '7';
        dB.SetDataBufferChar('7', selection, count);
        data = dB.GetDataBufferChar(selection, count);
        //data = '7';
        }
    else if (pos.y > GRABCHARSIZE) //8 
    {
        //dspWord[count] = '8';
        dB.SetDataBufferChar('8', selection, count);
        data = dB.GetDataBufferChar(selection, count);
        //data = '8';
        }
    else if (pos.y > 0) //9    
    {       
        //dspWord[count] = '9';
        dB.SetDataBufferChar('9', selection, count);
        data = dB.GetDataBufferChar(selection, count);
        //data = '9';
        }

        return data;
    break;
}
```

GetDataBufferChar:

```
char Data_Buffers::GetDataBufferChar(int bufferSelect, int count)
{
    char letter;
    switch (bufferSelect)
   {
   case EXERCISE:
    {
        letter = dspWord[count];
        break;
    }
    case SETS:
    {
        letter = setsNum[count];
        break;
    }
    case REPS:
    {
        letter = repsNum[count];
        break;
    }
    case WEIGHT:
    {
        letter = weightNum[count];
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        letter = '\0';
        break;
    }

    }

    return letter;
}
```

SetDataBufferChar:

```
void Data_Buffers::SetDataBufferChar(char data, int bufferSelect, int count)
{


switch (bufferSelect)
    {
    case EXERCISE:
    {
        dspWord[count] = data;
        break;
    }
    case SETS:
    {
        setsNum[count] = data;
        break;
    }
    case REPS:
    {
        repsNum[count] = data;
        break;
    }
    case WEIGHT:
    {
        weightNum[count] = data;
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;

    }

}
```

DrawBufferChar:

```
char Draw_Stuff::DrawBufferChar(SWTFT tft, Data_Buffers dB, int selection, int count, int charSpace)
{
char data;
data = dB.GetDataBufferChar(selection, count);
tft.drawChar(TEXTXPOS*charSpace, TEXTYPOS + 30, data, BLACK, WHITE, EXTTEXTSIZE);
return data;

}
```

Main loop:

```
dspWord[wordCount] = writeKeyboard.WriteKeybrdNum(p, dataBuffer, selection, wordCount); 
Serial.print("data\t"); Serial.println(dspWord[wordCount]);// Serial.print("\n"); 
dspWord[wordCount] = drawStuff.DrawBufferChar(tft, dataBuffer, selection, wordCount, wordSpace);
Serial.print("data1\t"); Serial.println(dspWord[wordCount]); //Serial.print("\n");
```

The Get and Set functions are storing data and getting data from buffers that are established as private buffers in Data_buffers class. The whole point is to be able to set these data buffers in one function, and get them using another function. For the first serial print, the data that is being set in the WriteKeybrdNum function is actually displayed. Then when I call DrawBufferChar, the second serial port print has no data. Am I missing something here. Both DrawBufferChar and WriteKeybrdNum are calling the exact same GetDataBufferChar function with the same "selection" and same "wordCount" yet data is being returned in one function and not the other. Doesn't make sense to me.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't C code. Perhaps you meant to tag as C++?

Comment: lot of duplicated code: `'9' - (pos.y / GRABCHARSIZE)` could simplify your code by removing all the `else if`

Comment: Thanks, Ill look into that